# How to connect to a ZMQ_REQ socket to another endpoint, once sending to the original address has timed-out?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am trying to make a **`ZMQ_REP`** socket connect to a new address when connecting to a first socket did not work out.

The main question concerns a problem that occurs when the user provides an incorrect socket endpoint.
 **Eg**.: the server is located at endpoint: `tcp://127.0.0.1:12345`
but the user tries to connect to endpoint `tcp://127.0.0.1:12346` (note the **`6`** instead of 5 in the port number).
Now I send a message to the server and the server should reply with another message. If this operation results in a timeout ( **`ETIMEOUT`** ), I want the program to connect to a new address, specified by the user.

Below is a lot of code but please focus on the thread and the main function. The other functions are included so the entire program is compilable. The thread function acts as a server for the main function which acts as a client. If you compile the program you can just run it and the main function will connect to the proper function. However, if you specify an endpoint as argument of the program it will fail (unless you specify the correct endpoint of course).

So I hope someone knows how I can make a socket connect to a new socket/endpoint?

I always keep either getting **`ETIMEOUT`** even when the user specifies the correct endpoint when he/she is prompted.

I compile the code like this:

> `g++ program.cpp -std=c++0x  $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libzmq ) -Wall -pedantic -g`

Where **`libzmq`** is version 2.2.0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <zmq.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

/*forward declarations.*/
char* recv_str( void* socket, int options=0 );
int send_string ( void* sock, const char* message, int opt = 0);

void 
thread_func ( void* context, std::string address, string identifier )
{
    int rc;
    void* socket = zmq_socket( context, ZMQ_REP);
    if ( !socket ){
        perror( "__LINE__: " );
    }
    std::cout << identifier << " binding to: " << address << endl;
    rc = zmq_bind ( socket, address.c_str() );
    if (rc != 0){
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        cout << error << endl;
    }

    int running = 1;
    while ( running ) {
        char* message;
        message = recv_str( socket );
        cerr << "recieved: " << message << endl;

        if ( strcmp( message, "stop" ) == 0 ){
            rc = send_string( socket, "stopping" );
            if (rc)
                perror( "Unable to send string" );
            assert ( rc == 0);
            running = 0;
        }
        else if( strcmp ( message , "reply" ) == 0 ){
            int rc = send_string( socket, (string("reply = ") + identifier).c_str() );
            if (rc)
                perror( "Unable to send string" );
            assert ( rc == 0);
        }
        else 
            send_string ( socket, "error" );
    }
    zmq_close(socket);
    cout <<  "Server is stopping."<< endl;
}

int main ( int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rc;     //returnvalue a to check whether function succeed
    char* msg;  //recieved messages.

    /*The address the server binds to.*/
    const char* addr1 = "tcp://127.0.0.1:12345";

    /*If no argument is given the address to which we connect is equal
     *to the server addres.*/
    const char* caddr = addr1;

    if ( argc == 2 ){ //so we can provide a custom addres.
        caddr = argv[1];
    }

    void* c = zmq_init(1);

    void* sock = zmq_socket( c, ZMQ_REQ);

    //timeout of 500ms
    int timeout = 500;
    size_t s = sizeof(timeout);
    rc = zmq_setsockopt(sock, ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, s);
    //rc = zmq_setsockopt(sock, ZMQ_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, s);
    if ( rc ){
        perror("Couldn't set sock opt: ");
        return 1;
    }

    //starting server inside thread.
    std::thread t1 ( &thread_func, c, addr1, "one" );

    /*check if server exists and reconnect if not*/
    int connected = 0;

    /*connect to the server.*/
    rc = zmq_connect( sock, caddr );
    rc = send_string( sock, "reply");
    assert ( rc == 0);
    msg = recv_str( sock);
    if ( msg != NULL) {
        connected = 1;
        free (msg);
    }

    /*if not connected retry with user input*/
    string current = caddr;
    while ( !connected ) {
        /*connect to the server.*/
        cout << "Unable to connect to " << current << "\nplease provide a new addres: " ;
        cin >> current;
        rc = zmq_connect( sock, current.c_str() );
        assert ( rc == 0);
        send_string(sock, "reply");
        msg = recv_str(sock);
        if ( msg ){
            connected = 1;
            free(msg);
        }
    }

    /*do something hopefully more useful than this with the server.*/
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        send_string ( sock , "reply" );
        msg = recv_str( sock );
        std::cout << msg << endl;
        free(msg);
    }
    send_string ( sock , "stop" );
    msg = recv_str (sock);
    cout << "Got " << msg <<endl;

    /*we are finished with msg.*/
    if (msg)
        free(msg);

    t1.join();
    cout << "Thread joined " << endl;

    /*terminate zmq related resources.*/
    zmq_close(sock);
    zmq_term( c );

    return 0;
}

/*Returns a string from a socket, the caller must free the string.*/
char* recv_str( void* socket, int options )
{
    int rc = 0;     //return value for functions that can faile
    size_t size;    //for message size
    zmq_msg_t msg;  //our message

    if ( (rc =zmq_msg_init( &msg ) ) !=  0 ){
        return NULL;
    }

    //recieving message
    rc = zmq_recv( socket, &msg, options);
    if (rc) {
        perror("While recieving msg");
        zmq_msg_close(&msg);
        return NULL;
    }
    size = zmq_msg_size( &msg );
    char *str = (char*)malloc (size+1); //reserve sizeof message + '0'
    if ( ! str){
        zmq_msg_close(&msg);
        return NULL;
    }

    /*copy message content to string */
    memcpy( str, zmq_msg_data(&msg), zmq_msg_size(&msg) );

    /*free msg*/
    zmq_msg_close(&msg);

    /*we can't assume caller sends a nullbyte on the line.*/
    str[size] = '\0';
    return str;
}

int send_string ( void* sock, const char* message, int opt ) {
    int rc;
    size_t size = strlen( message );
    zmq_msg_t msg;

    zmq_msg_init_size(&msg, size);
    memcpy ( zmq_msg_data(&msg), message, size);

    rc = zmq_send( sock, &msg, opt);
    zmq_msg_close(&msg);

    return rc;
}
```